# Traverse UIView.subviews to get button is swift

Tags: ios, swift, subviews

In my Objective-C code, I can use this method to find a `view.subviews`'s `button`:

```
-(UIButton*)findButtonInView: (UIView*)v {
    for (UIView *subView in v.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            return (UIButton*)subView;
        }
        else if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
            UIButton* btn = [self findButtonInView:subView];
            if(btn) {
                return btn;
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

UIButton* searchButton = [self findButtonInView:self.searchBar];
```

But how can I make a method to find `button` in `view` by Swift?

As you know I can not return `nil` like in this Swift method:

```
class func findButtonInView(_ view:UIView) -> UIButton {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class func findButtonInView(_ view:UIView) -> UIButton?{}
```